# how to find what isbns are in use

Tags: web-scraping, isbn

I am trying to find a list of what ISBNs are in use. I guess I could scrape a website like Amazon but that would waste a lot of bandwidth. Is there a better (free) way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up using partial list from http://my.linkbaton.com/isbn/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use the remote API for [isbndb.com](http://isbndb.com/data-intro.html).

Trying to keep an enormous ISBN list up-to-date yourself is quite a huge task if you ask me.

Comment: yeah I saw that previously, but their daily query limits are too low

Comment: Can someone with edit privileges correct the spelling above please? enormouse -> enormous

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record: note that if you actually want an ISBN for your publication, you need to go to the official agency in your country. In the US this is http://www.isbn.org/ , but it varies by country. In Australia, for example, it is [here](http://www.thorpe.com.au/isbn/).

Answer (score 0):

This might help: [What is the most complete (free) ISBN API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297700/what-is-the-most-complete-free-isbn-api)

As the accepted answer states there is also an API to search Amazon but it's not actually supposed to be used in the way you wish to.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, try isbndb.com